how to create a try-catch block in AJV code gen?
Node.js v18.16.0
"ajv": "^8.11.0",

When I tried to compile this:
ajv.addKeyword("isEven", {
  type: "number", // Applies to numbers
  code(cxt) {
    const { data, schema } = cxt;

    // Wrap validation code in a try-catch block
    cxt.gen.block(() => {
      cxt.gen
        .try(() => {
          if (schema === true) {
            // If schema is true, fail if the number is odd
            cxt.fail(_`${data} % 2 !== 0`);
          } else if (schema === false) {
            // If schema is false, always pass validation
            cxt.pass();
          } else {
            // Invalid schema value, throw an error
            throw new Error("'isEven' schema must be a boolean");
          }
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          // Handle runtime errors gracefully
          cxt.fail(_`"Validation error in 'isEven': " + ${e.message}`);
        });
    });
  },
  errors: true, // Enable custom error messages
});

I get this error:
Error: CodeGen: "try" without "catch" and "finally"

questions:

So I think my syntax may be off in how I need to implement the catch block. How to fix this?
Where is there official documentation in how to use AJV code gen?


https://ajv.js.org/ does not support try/catch

Use fail and throw

@mplungjan can you write an answer modifying my example with the fail and throw?

https://ajv.js.org does not support try/catch so it has to be removed like this
ajv.addKeyword("isEven", {
  type: "number", // Applies to numbers
  code(cxt) {
    const { data, schema } = cxt;

    if (schema === true) {
      // If schema is true, fail if the number is odd
      cxt.fail(_`${data} % 2 !== 0`);
    } else if (schema === false) {
      // If schema is false, always pass validation
      cxt.pass();
    } else {
      // Invalid schema value, throw an error
      throw new Error("'isEven' schema must be a boolean");
    }
  },
  errors: true, // Enable custom error messages
});


actually, the intention was to use a try-catch to handle the data. For example, if the data is some complex object, then the goal is to simply have a mechanism that catches all failures when handling it. Is that possible in ajv code gen?

I do not know. I just had a glance at the documentation.
